# How do I put a newly invited event into my iCal server calendar?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ical

We recently bought a mac-mini server which is running Snow Leopard Server for our office, and we have configured the server (using iCal Server 2) to store everybody's calendars.

Everyone is using iCal to access there calendars off the server and the basics are working ok (sharing etc).

An issue arises when someone attempts to create an event and invite another user in the office, the invitation is sent correctly but when the user receives the invitation and tries to add it to there calendar it is added to there local calendar, not the server calendar.

So my question is how do I make it so any newly added event is put into my server calendar, not one of my local calendars?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found this solution via Google](http://forum.addressbookserver.com/viewtopic.php?p=85&sid=e8c19137d0bd666a83e97c59e19b465c#p85) a while back and it helped me deal with some very annoying iCal shenanigans with a personal calendar and an Exchange calendar.  When other people sent me Exchange invites, the invites ended up in my personal calendar.  I always appeared as "Free" in Exchange even though I had a meeting scheduled in my personal calendar.